# VF compile error: standardsetController - void.Id

Tags: apex, visualforce, quote, standardsetcontroller

I have to build an quote tab using VF. Since it not possible using general config i am using VF page. I am getting an error while adding the filter and controller. Error is unknown Void.Id. Can someone help. I want to show filter values as "All" and the Status values one by one.
Below is my code.

**Page**

```
​<apex:page controller="QuotePageController" recordSetVar="quotes">
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="All Quotes">
     Filter: 
     <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!StatusPickvalue}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getQuotes}" rerender="table1"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Draft" itemValue="Draft" ></apex:selectOption>
                    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Accepted" itemValue="Accepted" ></apex:selectOption>
                    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Approved" itemValue="Approved"></apex:selectOption>
                    </apex:selectList>
                
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Quote Results" columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quotes}" var="c">                 
         <apex:column headerValue=" Quote Number"> <apex:outputlink value="/{!c.Id}" target="_blank">{!c.QuoteNumber}</apex:outputlink></apex:column>     
        <apex:column headerValue=" Quote Name"> <apex:outputlink value="/{!c.Id}" target="_blank">{!c.name}</apex:outputlink></apex:column>   
         <apex:column value="{!c.Status}"  headerValue="Status"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}" headerValue="Account Name "/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Opportunity.Name}" headerValue="Opp Name "/>
           
             
          </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock> 
      <!-- Pagination -->
<table style="width: 100%"><tr>

    <td>
        Page: <apex:outputText value=" {!PageNumber} of {! CEILING(ResultSize / PageSize) }"/>
    </td>            

    <td align="center">
        <!-- Previous page -->
<!-- active -->
<apex:commandLink action="{! Previous }" value="« Previous"
     rendered="{! HasPrevious }"/>
<!-- inactive (no earlier pages) -->
<apex:outputText style="color: #ccc;" value="« Previous"
     rendered="{! NOT(HasPrevious) }"/>

&nbsp;&nbsp;  

<!-- Next page -->
<!-- active -->
<apex:commandLink action="{! Next }" value="Next »"
     rendered="{! HasNext }"/>
<!-- inactive (no more pages) -->
<apex:outputText style="color: #ccc;" value="Next »"
     rendered="{! NOT(HasNext) }"/>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        Records per page:
<apex:selectList value="{! PageSize }" size="1">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="20" itemLabel="20"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="50" itemLabel="40"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Quotes_list"/>
</apex:selectList>
    </td>

</tr></table>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class QuotePageController {
    public string StatusPickvalue{get; set;}
    public list<Quote> QuoteList{get; set;}
    public void getQuotes() {
        QuoteList = new list<Quote>([SELECT Id, QuoteNumber, Name, Status from Quote WHERE Status =: StatusPickvalue]);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your issue is you are using `quotes` in two places for two conflicting use cases

**As RecordsetVar**

```
​<apex:page controller="QuotePageController" recordSetVar="quotes">
```

**As Getter in controller**

```
public void getQuotes() {
        QuoteList = new list<Quote>([SELECT Id, QuoteNumber, Name, Status from Quote WHERE Status =: StatusPickvalue]);
    }
```

Assuming your use case involves a standardsetController (i.e. a list of Quotes), then change the action method `getQuotes` to some other name (although one really wants to exploit the `getRecords()` method of the standardsetController to fetch the SObjects rather than an explicit SOQL

Comment: nice catch......